# While attache angular.js file console throw Error: error:modulerr

Tags: angularjs

I want to attach angular JS file to my project

```
<script src="js/global/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>        
<script src="js/global/angular-route.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

However, after I did that and went to my app url `http://localhost/demo3/` console throws me `Error: error:modulerr`, however when I opened this file via file path (`file:///C:/wamp/www/demo3/index.html`) there is no error...

When I followed link to angular [**DOCS**](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=Demo&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:unpr%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.3.5%2F$injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3D%2524stateProvider%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fdemo3%2Fjs%2Fglobal%2Fangular.min.js:6:416%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fdemo3%2Fjs%2Fglobal%2Fangular.min.js:38:22%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fdemo3%2Fjs%2Fglobal%2Fangular.min.js:36:49)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.e%20%5Bas%20invoke%5D%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fdemo3%2Fjs%2Fglobal%2Fangular.min.js:36:310)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fdemo3%2Fjs%2Fglobal%2Fangular.min.js:35:23)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fdemo3%2Fjs%2Fglobal%2Fangular.min.js:35:129%0A%20%20%20%20at%20r%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fdemo3%2Fjs%2Fglobal%2Fangular.min.js:7:302)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fdemo3%2Fjs%2Fglobal%2Fangular.min.js:34:428)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Lb%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fdemo3%2Fjs%2Fglobal%2Fangular.min.js:38:146) it says that i should load angular-routes. But I even didn't start write anything yet?! I don't have any other js files loaded at this time and routes are attached anyway.

What I did wrong?

EDIT:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo v3</title>        
        <meta charset="UTF-8">        
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="css/global/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="css/custom/common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>       
        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body ng-app="Demo">
        <div class="temp_mainFlexCont">
            <div class="template_menuFlexCont" ng-controller="LeftMenuController as Menu" ng-class="{'open': Menu.isMenuOpen}">
                <left-menu></left-menu>
            </div>
            <div class="template_contentFlexCont container-fluid">
                <section class="filter_tableContainer" ng-controller="UserfilterController as User">
                    <div class="row clearfix">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <h1>Users</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row filter_tableHeader">
                        <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-2">
                            <a class="filter_tableHeaderHref" href ng-class="{'active':User.fn_setlected_filter('f_name'), 'filter_sortDesc':User.fn_is_descending()}" ng-click="User.fn_set_sorting('f_name')">Name</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-2">
                            <a class="filter_tableHeaderHref" href ng-class="{'active':User.fn_setlected_filter('addr'), 'filter_sortDesc':User.fn_is_descending()}" ng-click="User.fn_set_sorting('addr')">Address</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-5">
                            <a class="filter_tableHeaderHref" href ng-class="{'active':User.fn_setlected_filter('desc'), 'filter_sortDesc':User.fn_is_descending()}" ng-click="User.fn_set_sorting('desc')">Description</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-2">
                            <a class="filter_tableHeaderHref" ng-class="{'active':User.fn_setlected_filter('rate'), 'filter_sortDesc':User.fn_is_descending()}" href ng-click="User.fn_set_sorting('rate')">Rating</a>
                        </div>                    
                    </div>
                    <div class="row filter_tableTbody">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">                        
                            <div class="row filter_tableRow" ng-repeat="user in User.obj_users">
                                <div class="col-xs-1">
                                    <div class="filter_imgContainer">
                                        <img class="img-responsive filter_avararImg" ng-src="img/avatars/{{user.img}}" alt=""/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>                            
                                <div class="col-xs-2">                                
                                    {{user.f_name.firstname}} {{user.f_name.lastname}}                                
                                </div>               
                                <div class="col-xs-2">
                                    {{user.addr.line_1}}<br> 
                                    <span class="small">{{user.addr.line_2}}</span>
                                </div>                            
                                <div class="col-xs-5">
                                    <p class="filter_tableDesc">
                                        {{user.desc}}
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-2">
                                    <span class="filter_rateStars" ng-repeat="a in User.fn_return_array_by_integer(5)| limitTo: user.rate track by $index">    
                                        &#x2605;
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="filter_rateStars notActive" ng-repeat="a in User.fn_return_array_by_integer(5)| limitTo: 5 - user.rate track by $index">    
                                        &#x2606;
                                    </span>
                                </div>                    
                            </div>                    
                        </div>
                    </div>            
                </section>
            </div>                                    
            <!-- global JS -->      
            <script src="js/global/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>        
            <script src="js/global/angular-route.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

            <!-- custom JS -->
            <script src="js/custom/common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
            <script src="js/custom/filters.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS Custom file

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('Demo', [
        'ngRoute'
    ]);

    app.controller('TemplateController', function () {

    });

    app.directive('leftMenu', function () {
        return{
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'views/left-menu.html'
        };
    });

    app.controller('UserfilterController', function () {
        this.int_male_counter = this.int_female_counter = 5;
        this.str_sort_by = {
            prop_name: 'f_name',
            order: 'asc'
        };
        this.obj_users = new Users(this.int_male_counter, this.int_female_counter).list;
        this.fn_set_sorting = function (str) {
            if (this.str_sort_by.prop_name === str) {
                this.str_sort_by.order = this.str_sort_by.order === 'des' ? 'asc' : 'des';
            } else {
                this.str_sort_by.order = 'asc';
                this.str_sort_by.prop_name = str;
            }
            this.obj_users.sortByObjKeyVal(this.str_sort_by.prop_name, this.str_sort_by.order);
        };
        this.fn_setlected_filter = function (str) {
            return str === this.str_sort_by.prop_name;
        };
        this.fn_is_descending = function () {
            return this.str_sort_by.order === 'des';
        };
        this.fn_return_array_by_integer = function (int) {
            return new Array(int);
        };
    });


    app.controller('LeftMenuController', function () {
        this.isMenuOpen = true;
    });

})();
```

Comment: Add `<base href='/demo3/'>` to your head tag in main index.html file

Comment: Try these hosted libraries: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>`. Also don't use min-versions while developing.

Comment: @simpe there is no differences while using hosted files

Comment: @underscore Unfortunately, this doesn't work

Comment: Then the problem lies elsewhere. Post the code for `index.html`

Comment: @simpe Right, I left ng-app while testing what is wrong. However I paste whole code of my app. I still have the same error.

Comment: Why are you starting the js file with `(function ()` ?

Comment: to create new JS scope instead working in global but it shouldn't affect anything